# Azure CosmosDB operation not supported when using $elemMatch and $in

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am doing a query like the following, which works fine with MongoDB, but sometimes fails with CosmosDB. I need it to work with both.

(`XXX` is a placeholder for any string value. All strings have unique values that are redacted for readability, and actual content should be of no significance.)

```
{
  server_index: {
    $elemMatch: {
      server: "XXX",
      index: "XXX",
      delete_time: { $exists: false },
      path: {
        $in: ["XXX", "XXX", "XXX" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The schema of a document is somewhat like this:

```
{
  ...,
  server_index: [
    {
      server: "XXX",
      index: "XXX",
      delete_time: ISODate(...),  // optional
      path: "XXX"
    },
    {...},  // same as above
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

This query sometimes works as expected with CosmosDB as well, but sometimes I also get the following response:

```
{
  _t: "OKMongoResponse",
  ok: 0,
  code: 115,
  errmsg: "Command is not supported",
  $err: "Command is not supported"
}
```

What is especially strange is that the query seemingly succeeds, and the response above is returned by a "valid" cursor as the first document, which then causes my document parser "crash".

I am using the C++ legacy driver. Is this even supported by Cosmos DB?

(According to the developer I inherited this project from, it is, and as always when you inherit projects, it all worked fine according to the previous developer... So this may be due to a change in Cosmos DB, due to the nature of my test data, or who knows what...)

Side note: In MongoDB, there is a multi-key index on `server_index`, which looks like this:

```
{
    "server_index.delete_time" : 1,
    "server_index.server" : 1,
    "server_index.index" : 1,
    "server_index.path" : 1
}
```

Is this even supported in CosmosDB?

EDIT: Trying to add this index with Robo 3T silently fails, with no error message whatsoever. The index is simply not added. Nice!

(Please don't ask about the strange database schema. It is like it is for a reason, and believe me, I, too, would like to burn it all down and replace it with something else ... I am open for suggestions for alternative queries, though)

Comment: These are probably better questions to raise with CosmosDB support. MongoDB drivers are not tested with Cosmos: the expectation is that their API will correctly emulate MongoDB server behaviour. Note that Cosmos has a different approach to indexing and the Cosmos documentation currently recommends creating [multiple individual indexes instead of a single compound index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#creating-compound-indexes). Can you edit your question to include an example of the query that returns this error intermittently?

Comment: @Stennie The query is in my question. Only the string values are different from "XXX", and they are all different from each other. All strings are upper-case, but it doesn't matter, since the issue is not matching but an error. My question mostly boils down to 1) Which part of my query is not supported and 2) Why am I getting an error as part of a query result (returned from a cursor), rather than the query itself failing, as one would expect?

Comment: Since the problem is intermittent and specific to CosmosDB, I still think this is an issue best raised with their support team. Returning a response instead of a cursor sounds like a bug and the "command is not supported" error could be improved to give some hint on what command failed. I would expect predictable failure if a command isn't supported.

Comment: @Stennie I agree and I also think it looks like a server-side bug. Just needed a second opinion on this. I will see if there are any server-side diagnostics that can shed light on this and maybe raise a support request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was probably a server-side problem. It seemed wrong in the first place (error status returned as part of the query result), and it has disappeared after a couple of weeks without me changing anything.